# Compare programming paradigm efficiency in Angular 2

Tags: performance, angular, architecture

I am new to Angular 2

Is there a comparative study of the efficiency of different code samples to justify the support of different architectural decisions?

I am expecting that if someone recommend a particular approach to have a measurable test to show in what aspects and what amounts is superior.

Mabe paradigms can not be compared as they are optimized for their specific purpose but something simple should exist like: use enum+array over switch because is 10 times faster from 1 million keys up.

I hope you understand what I am looking for.

Comment: Since the code is running client-side and is focused on client-side activities (which should NOT include processing 1 million keys!) ... most of the optimization focus is not on programming paradigms but rather on getting the smallest bundles, downloading the smallest amount of stuff, and potentially doing server-side rendering. So I'm not sure you will find what you are looking for.

Comment: There is a style guide here: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide but it does not talk to the types of comparisons you are looking for.

Comment: I added earlier a link to a performance that I thought usefull, but as DeborahK observed, it was not related to Angular 2. So, I decided to delete my earlier comment to avoid confusion.